# Get command from keyboard shortcut

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, execute-command

Is there a way to get the command that is executed when a keyboard shortcut is pressed?

E.g., when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, the terminal is ran. Is there a terminal command or an application that would print `gnome-terminal` when I press this shortcut?

Comment: Since (as given in the previous answers) there is no 'easy' way, I print out a list of the shortcuts I use as an aide mémoire which I have ready to hand on my noticeboard, updated as required.

Comment: @Graham I'm trying to use the command to reverse that same process. I'd really like to know how to launch the `Super-a` applications overlay in Ubuntu from a command name! This will surely come in useful if I could do it generally - shame there appears not to be a way to do it

Comment: Think you're best asking a new question which reflects what you are looking an answer to.

Comment: @Graham I've already asked a new question, which can be found here r.e. applications overlay command: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1063798/applications-overlay-command

Comment: Much better constructed question to which I have added an upvote. Hope you get a response.