# Applications overlay command

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, menu

I'm trying to work out what function call opens the Applications overlay in Ubuntu 18.04 - this is the function call that runs when the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> shortcut is pressed in Ubuntu 18.04.

#### Applications overlay:

[image: Application Overlay in Ubuntu 18.04]

I've attempted to find an application that prints the function call from a given keyboard shortcut, but couldn't find anything. Googling generic words such as "applications overlay" didn't work either.

Furthermore, is there any way to find out these function calls in the future (e.g., documentation), as I feel I'm asking a very basic question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it! Bit long winded, and involved going through the discussion for the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> commit on `gnome-shell` (found [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/dd3484b93f3f846c98a331bdc7243f91d57b6ac8/js/ui/viewSelector.js)), then analyzing the code a little bit.

Finally, I used `gdbus` to execute the JavaScript, inspired from [this snippet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214856/how-to-reload-gnome-shell-theme-via-a-command) about loading themes from JavaScript. Final result is this beautiful snippet:

```bsh
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell \
  --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval \
  'Main.overview._dash.showAppsButton.checked = true;Main.overview.show();';
```

Comment: I hope your takeaway from this is the understanding that shortcuts need not *execute commands*, but you can execute commands that mimic shortcuts.

Comment: This is typical of GNOME-based desktops to have a dbus call for showing "start menu" or manipulate other UI elements. But IMHO having JavaScript there is just whole lot of yuck. Also, I second what muru said

Comment: @muru I'm not sure I understand fully. Is this not the command that is executed when the shortcut <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> is pressed?

Comment: Or does the word command explicitly mean "CLI command" in this context? Because I believe the shortcut *does* execute the JavaScript command in the answer

Comment: @NickBull yes, it explicitly means "CLI command" in this context. The shortcut results in some functions being called in code. Some shortcuts may result have those functions actually running an executable command, for example, the shortcut for a terminal or calculator. Most don't, like this one, or changing the volume, for example.

Comment: @muru Ah okay, gotcha! Maybe a lack of understanding of proper terminology on my behalf, I had already assumed it wasn't an actual "command" but instead either C or some other function call. I'll prefer your use of semantics on these topics in the future as they're more specific :) Thank you!

Comment: If either of you happen to know a better way of finding these function calls without searching through commit messages, I'd greatly appreciate knowing that too!